# Developing Rust app in buildroot (problem with cargo build --offline --locked)

Tags: rust, embedded-linux, rust-cargo, buildroot

I created a new buildroot package which is a Rust application built with cargo.

I followed the buildroot manual for Cargo packages, and my `.mk` is quite simple:

```
MY_RUST_APP_VERSION = 1.1.0
MY_RUST_APP_SITE = $(BR2_EXTERNAL_PATH)/package/my-rust-app
MY_RUST_APP_SUBDIR = my-rust-app
MY_RUST_APP_SITE_METHOD = local

# Release build for smaller size and faster execution
# cargo already builds as --release by default in buildroot
#MY_RUST_APP_CARGO_BUILD_OPTS = --release

$(eval $(cargo-package))
```

It builds fine when Cargo.toml has no dependencies added.

However, when I add the first external dependency to `Cargo.toml`, buildroot fails to download and build it:

```
[dependencies]
tracing = "0.1.40"
```

buildroot output:

```
error: no matching package named `tracing` found
location searched: registry `crates-io`
required by package `my-rust-app v1.1.0`
As a reminder, you're using offline mode (--offline) which can sometimes cause surprising resolution failures, if this error is too confusing you may wish to retry without the offline flag.
```

I see that buildroot by default invokes Cargo with `--offline` and `--locked` which makes it harder to add new crates to Cargo.toml.

How to remove these default flags? Or maybe the approach to development and building a local Rust package should be different?

```
make my-rust-app-reconfigure
>>> my-rust-app 1.1.0 Building
[...]
__CARGO_TEST_CHANNEL_OVERRIDE_DO_NOT_USE_THIS="nightly"
CARGO_UNSTABLE_TARGET_APPLIES_TO_HOST="true" CARGO_TARGET_APPLIES_TO_HOST="false"
CARGO_BUILD_TARGET="armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf"
CARGO_TARGET_ARMV7_UNKNOWN_LINUX_GNUEABIHF_LINKER=arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf-gcc
RUSTFLAGS="-Clink-arg=-Wl,--allow-multiple-definition"  cargo build --offline --release --manifest-path Cargo.toml --locked
```

Before posting the question, I also tried purging the build directory in hope it will allow Cargo to build. However even `make my-rust-app-dirclean && make my-rust-app-reconfigure` doesn't help. I wanted to remove downloads from `buildroot/dl/` but cannot locate anything related to Rust dependencies. At the same time, I can successfully build from my package source directory with `cargo build`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to solve the problem. Instead of building a local package, I've placed the Rust code in a repository, and used buildroot's `git` method of installation.

`.mk` file looks like this:

```
MY_RUST_APP_VERSION = f799b21347968628fff067742d3a05e4152a1ba9 # git hash
MY_RUST_APP_SITE = git@github.com:org/repo.git
MY_RUST_APP_SITE_METHOD = git
MY_RUST_APP_SUBDIR = "packages/my-rust-app"

# Install steps
define MY_RUST_APP_INSTALL_TARGET_CMDS
    $(INSTALL) -D \
        $(@D)/target/$(RUSTC_TARGET_NAME)/release/my-rust-app \
        $(TARGET_DIR)/usr/bin/
endef

$(eval $(cargo-package))
```

Installing Rust/Cargo crate from git doesn't suffer from the limitations on local crate (`--offline`) and doesn't require additional steps like manually creating the `.lock` file and fetching the index.

Comment: Actually, it still uses `--offline`. Only, because it is doing a download, it will also do vendoring during the download. As explained in the other answer, for `local` site method, it is assumed that vendoring is already done.

Comment: Thanks for sharing @Arnout, you are right. Then do you know how to correctly do vendoring to enable the other answer to actually work with local method?

Comment: That is explained in the other answer to this question.

Comment: Not really. The top-voted answer, I carelessly upvoted it before I confirmed it actually works, and then I think others followed. And sometimes I would prefer to have Rust package directly in my buildroot ext tree than having to put the code in a separate git repo.

Answer (score 3):

The issue you're facing is due to the `--offline` flag that Buildroot uses when invoking Cargo. This flag prevents Cargo from reaching out to the internet to download new crates, which is why you're seeing the error when you add a new dependency.

To solve this issue, you need to download the dependencies before building the package with Buildroot. Here's how you can do it:

1. First, you need to generate a `Cargo.lock` file with all the dependencies. You can do this by running `cargo generate-lockfile` in your project directory.
2. Then, you need to download the dependencies. You can do this by running `cargo fetch` in your project directory. This will download all the dependencies and store them in your local Cargo registry.
3. Now, you need to tell Buildroot to use the local Cargo registry instead of trying to download the crates from the internet. You can do this by setting the `CARGO_HOME` environment variable to the path of your local Cargo registry. You can add this line to your `.mk` file:

   ```
    MY_RUST_APP_ENV = CARGO_HOME=$(HOME)/.cargo
   ```
4. Finally, you need to tell Buildroot to use the `Cargo.lock` file you generated earlier. You can do this by adding this line to your `.mk` file:

   ```
    MY_RUST_APP_CARGO_ENV = CARGO_LOCKFILE_PATH=$(BR2_EXTERNAL_PATH)/package/my-rust-app/Cargo.lock
   ```

Now, when you build your package with Buildroot, it should be able to find all the dependencies in your local Cargo registry and build your package successfully.

Remember to replace `$(HOME)/.cargo` and `$(BR2_EXTERNAL_PATH)/package/my-rust-app/Cargo.lock` with the actual paths on your system.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. However, the line `MY_RUST_APP_ENV = CARGO_HOME=$(HOME)/.cargo` doesn't seem to be effective. It's not affecting the build variables. I needed to add it to the second line: `MY_RUST_APP_CARGO_ENV = CARGO_HOME=$(HOME)/.cargo CARGO_LOCKFILE_PATH=$(BR2_EXTERNAL_PATH)/package/my-rust-app/Cargo.lock` and it works.
However now cargo build has 2 copies of CARGO_HOME in the command line. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: The package still doesn't build.
`CARGO_HOME` is now specified twice in the cargo command line: `CARGO_HOME=/home/path-to-my-buildroot/output_my_board/host/share/cargo` and then as `CARGO_HOME=/home/filip/.cargo` which is the one I added. How to get rid of the first one?